# How do I call my private void methods in my program

Tags: c#

So for this assignment I have to use 3 methods and have it display the correct things, but I can't seem to figure out how to call my methods I have made. I've looked at my book and searched online and can't find anything. Hoping someone can help me!

```
            InitializeComponent();
    }
    const int ROCK = 1;
    const int PAPER = 2;
    const int SCISSORS = 3;
    int userWins = 0;
    int computerWins = 0;


    private void RockButton(int userChoice, int computerChoice, int PAPER, int SCISSORS)
    {
        if (userChoice == computerChoice)
            MessageBox.Show("It's a tie!");
        else if (computerChoice == PAPER)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You lose! Paper covers rock.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == SCISSORS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You win! Rock crushes scissors.");
        }
    }

    private void PaperButton(int userChoice, int computerChoice, int ROCK, int SCISSOR)
    {
        if (userChoice == computerChoice)
            MessageBox.Show("It's a tie!");
        else if (computerChoice == ROCK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You win! Paper covers rock.");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == SCISSORS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You lose! Scissors cuts paper.");
        }
    }

    private void ScissorsButton(int userChoice, int computerChoice, int PAPER, int ROCK)
    {
        if (userChoice == computerChoice)
            MessageBox.Show("It's a tie!");
        else if (computerChoice == PAPER)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You win! Scissors cuts paper");
        }
        else if (computerChoice == ROCK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You lose! Rock crushes scissors.");
        }
    }


    private void rockButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        userPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Rock;

        Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        int computerChoice = randomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 4);
        switch (computerChoice)
        {
            case ROCK:
                computerPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Rock;
                break;

            case PAPER:
                computerPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Paper;
                break;

            case SCISSORS:
                computerPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Scissors;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void paperButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        userPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Paper;

        Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        int computerChoice = randomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 4);
        switch (computerChoice)
        {
            case ROCK:
                computerPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Rock;
                break;

            case PAPER:
                computerPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Paper;
                break;

            case SCISSORS:
                computerPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Scissors;
                break;

        }

        userWinsLabel.Text = userWins.ToString();
        computerWinsLabel.Text = computerWins.ToString();
    }

    private void scissorsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        userPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Scissors;

        Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        int computerChoice = randomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 4);
        switch (computerChoice)
        {
            case ROCK:
                computerPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Rock;
                break;

            case PAPER:
                computerPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Paper;
                break;

            case SCISSORS:
                computerPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Scissors;
                break;

        }
    }

    private void playAgainButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Restart();
    }
}}
```

How do I call these methods for the when the button is clicked it will display what the method states?

Comment: So you've created some methods you have no idea how to call?

Comment: I'm new to programming, I haven't been able to attend class, and I'm just going off what some friend of mine said

Comment: I think you should explain more about what you're going to do. because you just wrote some methods and now you're going to develop an app based on them. that doesn't make really sense to me.

Comment: I'm making a rock paper scissors game, when you click rock it randomly generates for the computer and it determines if you win or not same thing with when you click a different button. I've created the program without methods just using if else statements but now we have to create it again using methods, the teacher said I can just modify my original code a bit and it should work

Comment: Is your application a WPF application? Have you hooked the buttons "OnClick" events to any event handlers in your code? If these event handlers (most likely called <buttonname_onclick> or something similar) are in the same class as the methods you listed above, your methods can remain private and be called from those event handlers.

Comment: Another word of advice: when trying to learn gui programming, don't just copy code from other people, do some reading on how the gui framework you are using is put together and expects to be used.

Comment: I made a form that has buttons, and text boxes. So your saying to have the method in the event handler? I tried putting that in and I got some other errors

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `private` members from outside the containing classes scope (Reflection let aside).

For the members to be callable from other classes/objects, those members have to be at least `internal` (when the caller resides in the same assembly) or `public`.

**EDIT**

If the calling class inherits from the class containing the members, the `protected` modifier would also work.

Comment: How does my friend get it to work with private void then? I have a screenshot of some of his code

Comment: As @nozzleman told you, a private class can only be used inside the class or it's nested classes (not derived classes)

Comment: @KyleMiller it would work if he calls those members only within the containing object.

Comment: Alright, I'm a noob when it comes to this coding stuff, I'm not the fastest learner at this stuff as it is not my expertise. Mind telling me where I have to move my code around to?

Comment: Well, maybe you should reproduce a minimal working example which demonstrates what you are trying to do and where you fail. Then update your question and I'm sure we can provide a solution which helps you. When in a hurry, try to make the methods you are failing to call public, and see if it works ;)

Comment: Tried public and still not working for me, I just give up I don't get any of it! Been struggling on this for too long